# Export all items of a content type across a site collection into Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, export, custom-content-type

I have a custom content type based on the default task content type with a couple of additional columns. Within my site collection I have a number of sub sites which all inherit this content type.

I have seen using the content query web part that I can return all items in a site of the same content type.

When viewing a list I can export data of that list to excel. What I would like to achieve is exporting a full list of all items based on my custom content type within the system in a similar way.

I know I can query the Sharepoint tables directly in excel but not sure how I would write such a query, or whether there is a better approach?

This workbook will automatically generate some graphs based on task status and through Excel Services I will publish them in a web part. Thanks.

Comment: Which version are you working with?

Comment: Apologies for negating that, i'm using Sharepoint Online